# Rebuilding large SQL indexes isn't changing the fragmentation percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a large database running on SQL Server 2005.   I query the DMV sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to get index fragmentation information.

I was shocked to see avg_fragment_size_in_percent reporting a large amount of indexes with very bad fragmentation levels (99% for a lot of them).  These are on tables with non-trivial page counts (500+ pages on the smallest ones).

I proceded to run the following on the worst offenders:

ALTER INDEX ALL ON myTable REBUILD WITH(ONLINE = ON)

I then re-queried sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats, however it reports exactly the same fragmentation levels before and after the index REBUILD.

Is this information cached, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what the index definition for that index is? What fields are included (what are their datatypes)?

Comment: Sure ... my current worst offender, amongst many, is a uniqueidentifier index (single column index) that happens to be a foreign key.  This one is showing 99.5991983967936% average fragmentation.

Comment: Hmm... I found this post on MSDN which is reporting the same behavior:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/ff4b379c-d9e3-432d-9528-2b3ea1cdce39

Comment: I too get this issue. I did a test and rebuilt an index then checked the fragmentation after and it said it was 100% fragmented. I then checked using the SQL Management Studio and it told me it was 0.29% fragmented. The data must be cached, but how do you force it to update the stats?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check into the FILLFACTOR parameter for indices - this can strongly influence your index fragmentation.

On a "busy" index with lots of insert, updates, delete, you should typically go for a fillfactor of between 70 and 90 percent - depending on how many varchar() fields you have.

On an index (especially clustered index) which is ever-increasing (INT IDENTITY, typically), you can use FILLFACTOR 0 (or 100 - both means the same) and you'll only see fragmentation from deletes.

To specify FILLFACTOR, use this syntax:

```
ALTER INDEX (indexname) 
  ON myTable REBUILD 
  WITH (ONLINE = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80)
```

Here's some more info on fillfactors and the influence on performance:

- [Create and modify SQL Server indexes properly](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/Article/10016/0/page/3)
- [Index fill factor and performance considerations](http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2005/06/index-fill-factor-performance.html)
- [Who cares about fill factors](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/whocaresaboutfillfactor/1196/)
- [Fill factor option on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191005%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Hope this helps a bit!

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're getting the fragmentation of indexes?  There are more objects than just indexes in sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats - for example heaps (tables without clustered indexes) are in there as well.

Try inner joining on sys.indexes to limit yourself to Indexes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that ... yes, I am getting indexes by joining sys.indexes on the object_ids.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you ever wanted to know about SQL Fragmentation and how to deal with it can be found at [SQLFool](http://sqlfool.com/2009/03/automated-index-defrag-script/)

She has an amazing script for automating index defragmentation and is very helpful if you have questions.